# Laplace transformation for $T_{1}\cdot V'(t) + V(t) = K\cdot P(t) + Va$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to do a Laplace transform of the following equation:

$$T_{1}\cdot V'(t) + V(t) = K\cdot P(t) + Va$$

The purpose is to solve $V(s)$ equation knowing that $V(0) = Va$.
I followed all the transformation rules and I got the following result:

$$V(s) = \frac{K\cdot P(s)}{s\cdot (1 + T_{1})} + \frac{Va}{s}$$

But, according to the correction, the expected result is :

$$V(s) = \frac{K\cdot P(s)}{(1 + s\cdot T_{1})} + \frac{Va}{s}$$

Did I do something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Hi, your notation is not mathematical. For instance, I don't know what the dot in "K.p" means. You are more likely to receive an answer if you format your question in a more conventional way, see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @R_B: please check again .... is it better?

Comment: could you elaborate please how is it correct?

Comment: I added an answer Nechi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T_{1}\cdot V'(t) + V(t) = K\cdot P(t) + Va$$
Apply Laplace Transform:
$$T_{1}(sV(s)-V(0)) + V(s) = K\cdot P(S) + \dfrac {Va}s$$
$$V(s)(sT_{1} + 1) = K\cdot P(S) + \dfrac {Va}s+T_1V(0)$$
Since $V(0)=Va$ we have:
$$V(s)(sT_{1} + 1) = K\cdot P(S) + \dfrac {Va}s+T_1Va$$
$$V(s)(sT_{1} + 1) = K\cdot P(S) + \dfrac {Va(1+sT_1)}s$$
It finally gives:
$$V(s) = K\cdot \dfrac {P(S)}{(sT_{1} + 1)}  +\dfrac {Va}s$$
So yes the result of the correction is correct.

Comment: Now I see my error .... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @nechi